# Can Enterprise Keyword be a column for a CoreResults Webpart

Tags: search, enterprise-keywords

In my CoreResults Webpart 'Fetched Properties' I tried to add

```
<Column Name="TaxKeyword" />
```

returns: "Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings."
So then I tried its hidden field

```
 <Column Name="TaxKeywordTaxHTField"/>
```

got the same error. What do I have to do for this field to appear in my core results webpart?